# I am using a C# encryptor for my app to write encrypted messages to a file,and looking for a way to verify it is the original file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encryption, base64, aes

So I have a text file encryption application I've written in C# windows forms, it encrypts the message entered in the text box and saves the encrypted version of the message to the file. The user then must enter the date the file was created, it checks this to open the file. But I am wondering, would it be possile to add extra security to verify it is for sure the original file the program created and not an imposter txt file?

Here is the encryption class, thank you.

```
    class Encryptor1

    {
        public static string IV = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a";
        public static string Key = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a13";

        public static string Encrypt(string decrypted)
        {
            byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
            AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            endec.BlockSize = 128;
            endec.KeySize = 256;
            endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
            endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
            endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateEncryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
            byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
            icrypt.Dispose();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
        }

        public static string Decrypted(string encrypted)
        {

            DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\encryptedmessagehere.txt");

            string asString = creation.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");


            var created = Form2.keyhere;
            if (created != asString)
{
                string message = "That is incorrect, access is denied.";
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
            else if (created == asString)
            {

                byte[] textbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
                AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                endec.BlockSize = 128;
                endec.KeySize = 256;
                endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
                endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
                endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
                byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
                icrypt.Dispose();
                return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(enc);

            }

            return encrypted;
        }
    }
}
```

I can supply the code that creates the file if needed, it is just an ordinary txt file. Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. A user is typing a message that get's encrypted and saved to a file on a device. The user known when the saving took place and uses this as "key" to get access later to decrypt the message. How can an imposter save a message with same filedate/time ? When the imposter has write access to the device he can encrypt another message, saves the file and changes the creation date - ok. So you should prevent the direct access to the message storage device. 2.: you should use a key derivation method to retrieve the encryptkey - you are using static key&iv=**UNSAFE**.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Message Authentication Code (MAC) that can be used to determine if any bits in either the ciphertext (or the plaintext, see below) have been modified in any way.

For instance, in C# you can use HMACSHA256 for this. You need a separate MAC key in addition to your symmetric encryption key.

The basic idea is to do something like: encrypt the plaintext using your encryption key and initialization vector.

Concatenate the initialization vector and the ciphertext.

Use your MAC key to computer a MAC on the combined iv + ciphertext.

Concatenate the MAC to the initialization vector + ciphertext. You now have a sequence of bytes: [MAC][IV][Ciphertext].

When you go to decrypt the file you first extract the MAC from the beginning of the byte sequence. Then, use the MAC key to compute the MAC over the iv + ciphertext bytes. Now compare the result with the MAC that you extracted. If they match, you know no data tampering has occurred and that the plaintext you get when you decrypt the ciphertext is the original that was present at the same time the original encryption and generation of the MAC took place.

You can also generate the MAC on the plaintext and then encrypt that along with the plaintext and do the MAC validation after decrypting. It's usually better to do the (faster) MAC validation before bothering to do the actual decryption of the full payload, which is more expensive.

Comment: The first suggestion is called encrypt-then-MAC and the last one MAC-then-encrypt. The first one is usually [better](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/205/13022).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into hashing. It is essentially a function that converts any data into a mostly unique, fixed amount of characters. You can store the hash somewhere and then compare it with the hash of this other file to ensure that it is not an imposter.